# Why there is memory usage difference between xmx and top?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I set the xmx of jvm equals to 4 G, but after running for a time, when I use top to see the memory, it shows the process used 12 G memory.

So what the xmx actually mean? what should I do if I want to limit the jvm memory to 4 G ?

command line:   -server -Xms4g -Xmx4g

And another related question :)

If the gc happens, will the space of the objects that not used any more in young generation be   inevitably released by JVM ? or some of them left to the next gc ?

thanks

Comment: How do you *"set the xmx of jvm equals to 4 G"*? From the command line? Can you show the exact command line you are using?

Comment: Can you try with pmap $pid and see what is the usage.?

Comment: You can use JConsole to check the actual heap size. Also to check if your settings are picked up by JVM

Comment: Are you looking at RSIZE or VSIZE? that is are you sure you're not looking at the virtual memory usage?

Answer (score 7):

The -Xmx option to the JVM specifies the `maximum size of the Java
garbage collected heap`. It does NOT limit the size of the memory used by the JVM. The size of the process reported by ps or top will
include that, plus any other memory used by the process. The following
are examples of things that are not part of the garbage collected heap
and yet are part of the memory required by the process:

- Code to implement the JVM
- The C manual heap for data structures implementing the JVM
- Stacks for all of the threads in the system (app + JVM)
- Cached Java bytecode (for libraries and the application)
- JITed machine code (for libraries and the application)
- Static variables of all loaded classes

Comment: +1 I would add direct ByteBuffers and memory mapped files which can easily be in the GBs (even 100s of GB)  for some prorgams.