# Why java Xmx option is not used when I invoke program using java command?

Tags: java, performance, jvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why there is memory usage difference between xmx and top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922418/why-there-is-memory-usage-difference-between-xmx-and-top)

I run a java program using

```
java    -Xms32m -Xmx64m  xxxclassname
```

but from top command, I know there is a birst of memory which is nearly 200MB. Why it is not less than 64MB as specified in the Xmx option?

Comment: @RNJ what is the relation betweeen -Xmx64m and jvm loading?

Comment: The heap is not all the memory used. Much of the additional memory you see is shared memory not private to the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're specifying the maximum size of the garbage-collected heap. There are other aspects to Java memory consumption, including native code (not just the JVM, but also any native libraries loaded with JNI) and [PermGen](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/presenting_the_permanent_generation) space. (PermGen space can be tuned somewhat, but you really don't want to confine it too much, or your program will crash.)

Answer (score 4):

The

```
-Xmx64m
```

flag only controls the *heap size*. Java needs much more memory than this to function properly.

Comment: how many parts of memory constitute the who memory that java uses?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11922764/1343161) gives a few examples of things that are stored outside of the heap.